# An exemple that convergence in probability does not imply convergence almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, almost-everywhere

In my lecture notes, there is the following example to study in order to show that convergence in probability does not imply convergence almost surely.

We consider the measurable space $([0,1], \mathcal{B}([0,1]), \lambda)$ and the random variable defined by $X_n(\omega) = \mathbb{1}_{[\frac{n}{2^{k(n)}}, \frac{n+1}{2^{k(n)}}]}(\omega)$. $k(n)$ is defined as the unique integer such that $2^{k(n)-1}\leq n < 2^{k(n)}$ and we notice that $k(n)$ form an increasing sequence and start at $1$.

The idea is to consider $\varepsilon\in]0,1[$ and notice that

$$
\mathbb{P}(\lvert X_n \rvert > \varepsilon) = \mathbb{P}\left(\{\omega\in[0,1] : \frac{n}{2^{k(n)}}\leq \omega\leq \frac{n+1}{2^{k(n)}}\}\right) = \frac{1}{2^{k(n)}}
$$

Which tends to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity by the preceding remark on $k(n)$. So we conclude that $X_n$ converges in probability to $0$. Until here, that's fine. However, when I want to show that this is not a convergence almost surely, I am not so sure on what to do.

Using the definition of convergence almost surely, I would like to find a subset of $[0,1]$ with measure strictly positive on which $lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega) = 1$.

Has someone any idea on how to proceed, please ?

Thank you a lot

Comment: Such a subset cannot exist because it would contradict the convergence in probability.  I would suggest looking for a subset on which $\limsup X_n(\omega) = 1$ instead.

Comment: To add to user624's point, you do not need to show the limit goes to 1 for certain $\omega$ of positive measure. It is enough to show the limit does not exist for certain $\omega$ of positive measure. Actually you can show that for every $\omega \in [0,1]$, the limit does not exist since $X_n(\omega)$ infinitely bounces between 0 and 1 as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @user6247850 Thank you for the comment ! However I do not see where the existence of such a subset would contradict the convergence in probability since  it is not used on what I wrote for proving the convergence in probability in the sense that the limit of the lebesgue measure of the set I describe inside the probability (corresponding to the event $\lvert X_n\rvert > \varepsilon$) is still $0$ no ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: @coboy Well, if $\lim X_n(\omega) = 1$ for $\omega \in E$ where $\mathbb{P}(E) > 0$, then $\lim \mathbb{P}(|X_n| > \varepsilon) \ge \mathbb{P}(E) > 0$, so $X_n$ could not converge to $0$ in probability.  This uses essentially the same proof that almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability.

Comment: @user6247850 Thank you a lot ! The proof I’ve seen on almost surely implies convergence on probability was an application of DCT and I did not take the time to think about it as I should. But proving this by contraposition make appear your argument and a good reflexion . I cannot restrict the set to have a measure 0 since I can embed a set of measure strictly positive that does not depend on $n$. Finally, is it possible to see convergence for random variables with a link to convergence of functions ? The fact that we know a little on $\Omega$ make me think it would be hard but we never know !

Comment: @coboy I'm not sure what kind of link to convergence of functions you mean.  Random variables can, of course, be seen as functions on $\Omega$, so every mode of convergence for random variables is equivalent to a mode of convergence for functions, but I don't think that's quite what you had in mind

Comment: @user6247850 Yes I'm not clear sorry, I hope the following lines will help. For example, I see (wrongly, maybe) the convergence in probability as the convergence of the measure of a sequence of sets to $0$. I have never seen something like this when working on function in metric space, is this irrelevant to consider a measurable structure and this kind of convergence (in measure) when working outside the framework of random variable ?

Comment: @coboy It would probably be a good idea to ask that as a separate question instead of in the comments, but yes, convergence in measure is used outside of the context of random variables.

Comment: @user6247850 I think I have managed to pinpoint what my true question was through my questions in the comments. I posted it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754864/what-is-interesting-about-random-variable-from-a-mathematical-point-of-view?noredirect=1#comment10092173_4754864 if you're interested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example hides the point of the exercise with unnecessary computation.

Show that $k(n) = \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor +1$.

Let $I_n = [ {n \over 2^{k(n)} } ,{n+1 \over 2^{k(n)} } )$. Show that
$I_{2^m},...,I_{2^{m+1}-1}$ form a partition of $[{1 \over 2},1)$.

Hence for any $\omega \in [{1 \over 2},1)$, we see that $\liminf_n X(\omega) = 0, \limsup_n X(\omega) = 1$.