# What is interesting about random variable from a mathematical point of view?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, random-variables

I'm studying probabilities and I'm wondering if I'm missing something. It turns out that I don't see the significance of the concept of a random variable. Indeed, from what I've understood, it's a measurable function defined on a slightly more general space than usual (not necessarily equipped with an algebraic or topological structure).

The term "random variable" comes from the fact that each element of the starting space corresponds to the occurrence or non-occurrence of an event, which is identified with a subset of $\Omega$ and is an element of the considered sigma-algebra.

But I don't see the point of discussing "random variables" (instead of measurable functions) in mathematics since the entire probabilistic analysis is a particular case of classical analysis on measurable spaces.

So, I'm wondering if there's a reason or subtlety that I'm unaware of.

Lastly, this leads me to question what mathematical concept is purely probabilistic?

Thank you a lot

Comment: There is the leap of faith that consists on saying "this thing in the real world satisfies these axioms", which makes the people who use it hundreds of times more money than those studying measurable functions.

Comment: Regarding the last question, how about Brownian Motion?

Comment: @Alborz Brownian motion is a mathematical description of a physical phenomenon, so I would qualify it as a mathematical object whose properties we will study, for example. However, it is inseparable from the physical phenomenon it describes; it's a modeling. Examples of what I mean by mathematical concepts: the concept of continuity is a topological concept, the concept of a vector space is an algebraic concept.

Comment: @coboy I'd argue that there are no 'strictly mathematical' concepts that are probabilistic, as probability (often) is interpreted as the long-run frequency of occurrence. This concept requires something to 'occur', and this 'occurring' happens either in the real world or a theoretical experiment. I don't see either of these being in the realm of purely mathematical constructions.

Comment: @coboy also as with any loose naming of categories I think the definitions are not tight enough for much meaningful discourse here. Why should vector space be considered an algebraic concept purely? Are vector spaces and continuity not a 'modelling' as well? At what point does a 'model' differ from a 'purely mathematical' construct, if that even exists? Maybe it's overly pedantic but I think if something belongs to one group or not largely comes down to personal feeling regarding the subject. All mathematical objects model something to an extent.

Comment: It must be whatever additional structure we assume that allows us to prove theorems like the central limit theorem. Even if probability had no real world applications, we can be sure that pure mathematicians would still know and love the central limit theorem.

Comment: @Alborz It is clear that establishing the right definitions is essential, but I find it quite complicated. I agree with you that every mathematical concept is a product of our reflection's inherent connection to the environment that surrounds us. However, some of these concepts seems more "profound" in the sense that they have managed to detach themselves, at least seemingly, from any notions other than mathematical ones and appear to exist for and by themselves. It's likely this kind of notion that I would refer to as "mathematical concepts" but this is my own reflection, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measure theory is of course critically important to probability theory, and in many ways they are extremely similar and overlapping in parts.  I would say one of the biggest distinguishing features is the role of the $\sigma$-algebra.  In a measure theory context, the $\sigma$-algebra is often not particularly interesting: there is a single one in the background, and we look at functions that are all measurable with respect to it.  In probability theory, there are often many $\sigma$-algebras running around, and we are interested in the relationships between those $\sigma$-algebras.  Of course, there is nothing preventing one from looking at multiple $\sigma$-algebras in classical measure theory, but this difference in focus is one of the distinguishing features of probability theory.  For example, if one has a random variable $X$, then one often is also interested in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by it $\sigma(X)$, which is interpreted as the information one gains from observing $X$.  One can define $\sigma(f)$ for a measurable function $f$, but I don't know where it would be used in classical analysis.

As for concepts that are purely probabilistic: I would say independence is purely probabilistic.  We say that two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal F, \mathcal G$ are independent if $\mu(A \cap B) = \mu(A)\mu(B)$ for all $A \in \mathcal F$ and $B \in \mathcal G$, and two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent if $\sigma(X)$ is independent of $\sigma(Y)$.  This definition only makes sense if $\mu$ is a probability measure: since $\Omega \in \mathcal F$ for all $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal F$, in order for $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ to be independent we must have $\mu(\Omega) = \mu(\Omega \cap \Omega) = \mu(\Omega)\mu(\Omega) = \mu(\Omega)^2$.  This implies either that $\mu(\Omega)=0$ (in which case we're looking at a trivial measure that assigns measure $0$ to all sets), or that $\mu(\Omega)=1$, in which case we're looking at a probability measure.

Comment: This is the kind of insight I was looking for ! A big thanks.